# How to Stop Swiping the item in Recycler view after reaching some distance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have a Recycler View in android. I have attached an `ItemTouchHelper` to it.I have enabled only swiping from left to right.

So when i swipe any item of Recycler view , the item starts moving towards right and on the left i draw a text. 
This is fine . 
My requirement is that, I want allow user to swipe only to some distance , and when that distance is reached and user release the touch, the item being swiped should go back to its position towards left.

Problem is that , when i swipe left to right the view gets fully swiped out of the screen . How can i restrict it to be swiped only to some distance ?
How do i do it ?

Here is my code for the item touch callback:

```
private void initSwipe(){
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
            int position = viewHolder1.getAdapterPosition();
            MyItem item = dataList.get(position);
            if (item==null )return;
            if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                float width = height / 3;
                Paint p = new Paint();
                Paint textPaint = new Paint();
                textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                textPaint.setTextSize(20);

                if(dX > 0) {
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,(float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background,p);
                    //RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                    //c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                    c.drawText(item.getDate(),(float)(itemView.getLeft() + width),(float)(itemView.getBottom() - width), textPaint);
                }
            }
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecycler);
}`
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace this line in the onChildDraw:

```
super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
```

with the following, it sets the max x position to be at 100, adjust this value to your need.

```
float newDx = dX;
if (newDx >= 100f) {
    newDx = 100f
}
super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, newDx, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
```

[Then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159154/2069407) in the callback handler's onSwiped, call notifyItemChanged on the RecyclerView adapter.

```
 @Override
 public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
     int direction) {
         if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
    }
 }
```

A slight issue with notifyItemChanged is that you might notice a quick flash when the view is getting restored to it's original position.

Comment: Can we swipe it back to its original position without blinking ?

Comment: This works, but how to reduce swipe speed before it reach end like WhatsApp?

Comment: You can also control it by pasting this code snippet in your onChildDraw method `if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe)
            {
                if (dX < 0)
                {
                    itemView.TranslationX = dX / 5;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }`
//`itemView` is `viewHolder.ItemView`

Answer (score 0):

In super.onChildDraw you can use this: dX/5

```
override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
                val height = itemView.bottom.toFloat() - itemView.top.toFloat()
                val width = height / 3
                val p = Paint()
                if (dX < 0) {
                    p.color = Color.RED
                    val background = RectF(
                        itemView.right.toFloat() + dX,
                        itemView.top.toFloat(),
                        itemView.right.toFloat(),
                        itemView.bottom.toFloat()
                    )
                    c.drawRect(background, p)
                    val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        this@TimeLineFragment.resources,
                        R.drawable.ic_photo_delete
                    )
                    val margin = (dX / 5 - width) / 2
                    val iconDest = RectF(
                        itemView.right.toFloat() + margin,
                        itemView.top.toFloat() + width,
                        itemView.right.toFloat() + (margin + width),
                        itemView.bottom.toFloat() - width
                    )
                    c.drawBitmap(icon, null, iconDest, p)
                }
            } else {
                c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            }

            super.onChildDraw(
                c,
                recyclerView,
                viewHolder,
                dX / 5,
                dY,
                actionState,
                isCurrentlyActive
            )
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(binding.timeLineList)
```